# rewrite urls in a firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm writing a firefox addon, and if certain conditions are met, id like to rewrite the URL.
Right now its being done in the following fashion

```
if(checkUrl(document.location.href))
{
    document.location.replace('xyz.com');
}
```

the problem with this is that the old page loads, then the condition is met, and only then is the user redirected.

Is there a way to do this **before** the page loads? i.e., once the user has typed in the url and hit enter (or clicked?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

for any future readers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners

Answer (score -1):

If you place at the beginning of the body tag:

```
<script>
document.location.replace('xyz.com')
</script>
```

That should work.

Comment: again, this would only kick in once the original page loads.
i'm trying to get it done before the browser starts loading the page, to save that extra flicker as the user gets redirected.

Comment: Ah... then you need to do it server side, using a mod rewrite or another method

Comment: Sorry for the noise, you are in a firefox plugin... no server here